# Hashcode with generic types

Tags: java, guava, apache-commons, guava-testlib

Looking for a method to easily calculate hashes for arbitrary types. Given the following class:

```
class Foo<T> {
    ...
    T value;
}
```

I have already overridden the `equals` method using `Objects.deepEquals` to compare the `value` fields. Is there an easy way to do the same with `hashCode`? Some utility method in guava or apache commons (i'm already using them for other things) ?

Unfortunately `Objects.hash(field1, ... , value)` does not work when value is an array.

I know one option is to do

```
Arrays.deepHashCode(new Object[]{ field1, ... , value });
```

but it feels wrong to create a new array for that instead of just looping it

Comment: I would just use value.equals() and value.hashCode(): arrays don't fit well with generics, they should generally not be used, and if they are (instead of Lists, for example), the caller should know that two distinct arrays are never equal. Just look at, for example, the List<T> class. Two List<T> are equal if their elements are equal. It doesn't care if the elements are arrays.

Comment: Guava doesn't really have anything for this problem because they recommend [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(object)`  in commons-lang3.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html